# parse through urllib2 in python

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to convert following statement from `urllib` to `urllib2` equivalent statement

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode( {'status': msg} )
```

I can import only `urllib2` and `urlparse`.

Comment: `urllib2` is not really the "2nd version" of `urllib`. It's not possible to "translate" all functionality from `urllib` to `urllib2`

Answer (score 1):

`urllib2` is not really the "2nd version" of `urllib`. It's not possible to "translate" all functionality from `urllib` to `urllib2`.

Even [the documentation for `urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) states that you should use `urllib` for URL encoding.

Extracted from the [`urllib2.urlopen` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

> ...data should be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-**urlencoded format**. The `urllib.urlencode()` function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples and returns a string in this format.